# How to route JAX-RS request conditionally, depending on the suffix?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
@Path("/finder")
public class Finder {
  @Path("/{name}")
  public Proxy find(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    Object found = /* some object found by name */
    return new Proxy(found);
  }
}
public class Proxy {
  private Object obj;
  public Proxy(Object found) {
    this.obj = found;
  }
  @GET
  @Path("/")
  public String info() {
    return /* some meta-information about the object */
  }
  @Path("/")
  public Object passthru() {
    return this.obj;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to enable:

```
GET /finder/alpha -> Proxy.info()
GET /finder/alpha/something -> obj.something()
```

Am I going the right way? Meanwhile, Jersey says:

```
WARNING: A sub-resource method, public final java.lang.String com.XXX.Proxy.info(), 
with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine with the code above except that I don't need `@Path("/")` annotation at `info()`.