# What does this strange Jersey warning mean?

Tags: java, jersey

What does this warning mean in Jersey 1.4:

```
WARNING: A sub-resource method, public final java.lang.String com.XXX.render(), 
with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
```

This is how the method looks:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/")
public final String render() {
  return "test";
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Why do you need specify such path for method? @Get is enough to tell jersey that it is default method for entire class (I'm assuming that your class has some @Path("/MyRes") annotation).

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka the same thing, POST is handled by strictly specified URL, that can be formed by root + method

Comment: Great. So I conclude that just specifying '@POST' is enough and '@Path("/")'. Thanks.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka depends on your task. If your class has only 1 method (or 1 method for each VERB) then it is ok

Comment: What's VERB? I have only one method that's defined as `@POST` without any `@Path`.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka VERBs are: POST, PUT, GET, HEAD, DELETE
And then it is ok if you have only single method

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had the same problem last week with [How to route JAX-RS request conditionally, depending on the suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276882/how-to-route-jax-rs-request-conditionally-depending-on-the-suffix) - any luck fixing it there?

A look around on the net reveals you may have set-up your constructor incorrectly - have a read through http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Problem-using-the-JerseyTest-class-td3256608.html - someone who had a similar problem and was able to resolve it.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved already, as suggested by Dewfy. Works perfect without this redundant `@Path("/")` annotation.