# How do I run the Hetionet v1.0 docker container?

Tags: shell, docker, neo4j, digital-ocean

I'm trying to run the [Hetionet v1.0 docker](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/tree/neo4j-3.0/hetnet/neo4j/docker#deploying-the-docker) container mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370820/hosting-a-public-read-only-neo4j-instance-in-the-cloud).

1. I've [setup a digitalocean droplet with Docker](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-docker-application)
2. I ran `docker pull dhimmel/hetionet` and it worked
   [image]
3. Now I run `docker run dhimmel/hetionet` and the following happens (and never returns to the interactive shell prompt).
   [image]

If that completed successfully I think the last thing I'm supposed to do is run `sh ~/run-docker.sh`. Furthermore nothing is live at my droplet's ip_address:7474.

The error in the screenshot above looks a lot like it could be related to some redundant `@Path("/")` annotation, as described in [this SO post's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4333481/3491991), buried in the docker container but I'm not sure.

Is the output from running `docker run dhimmel/hetionet` supposed to hang my shell? I'm running a 2 GB Memory / 40 GB Disk Droplet on Ubuntu 16.04 with Docker 1.12.5.

Comment: Also feel free to open [issues](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/issues) on the `dhimmel/hetionet` GitHub -- especially for any issues that focus on running Hetionet in Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in the [Hetionet Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/dhimmel/hetionet/).

The output in 3 is expected. It looks like a Docker container successfully launched, downloaded the Hetionet database, and launched the Neo4j server. I'll look into [fixing the warnings](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/issues/2), but they're not errors, as Neo4j is still launching.

For production, we use a more advanced Docker [run command](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/blob/319673109a5f7948dd5618843bf0015e8dc776ff/hetnet/neo4j/docker/host/run-docker.sh). Depending on your use case, you may want to use the development docker [run command](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/blob/319673109a5f7948dd5618843bf0015e8dc776ff/hetnet/neo4j/docker/README.md#running-the-docker):

```
docker run \
  --publish=7474:7474 \
  --publish=7687:7687 \
  --volume=$HOME/neo4j/hetionet-data:/data \
  --volume=$HOME/neo4j/hetionet-logs:/var/lib/neo4j/logs \
  dhimmel/hetionet
```

Both the production and development command map ports. This will make it so the Neo4j server running inside your Docker container is available at http://localhost:7474/. This is most likely what you want. If you're doing this on DigitalOcean, you would replace `http://localhost` with the IP address of your droplet.

For an interactive shell session in a `dhimmel/hetionet` container, you can use:

```
docker run --interactive --tty dhimmel/hetionet bash
```

However, that command does not launch the Neo4j server -- it just let's you explore the image.

Does this clear things up?

Comment: Replied at github [issue: Can't run-docker.sh](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/issues/3)